# bash print first to nth column in a line iteratively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to get the column names of a file and print them iteratively. I guess the problem is with the `print $i` but I don't know how to correct it. The code I tried is:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {2..5}
do
  set snp = head -n 1 smaller.txt | awk '{print $i}'
  echo $snp
done
```

Example input file:

```
ID Name Age Sex State Ext
1  A    12   M    UT  811
2  B    12   F    UT  818
```

Desired output:

```
Name 
Age
Sex 
State
Ext
```

But the output I get is blank screen.

Comment: Don't set the variable in the loop, remove echo statement. That should suffice.

Comment: the set command is required as the output of the commands is passed from right. I did try setting the variable outside the loop. I get error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better just `read` the first line of your file and store the result as an array:

```
read -a header < smaller.txt
```

and then `printf` the relevant fields:

```
printf "%s\n" "${header[@]:1}"
```

Moreover, this uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only, and involves no unnecessary loops.

**Edit.** To also answer your comment, you'll be able to loop through the header fields thus:

```
read -a header < smaller.txt
for snp in "${header[@]:1}"; do
    echo "$snp"
done
```

**Edit 2.** Your original method had many many mistakes. Here's a corrected version of it (although what I wrote before is a much preferable way of solving your problem):

```
for i in {2..5}; do
    snp=$(head -n 1 smaller.txt | awk "{print \$$i}")
    echo "$snp"
done
```

- `set` probably doesn't do what you think it does.
- Because of the single quotes in `awk '{print $i}'`, the `$i` never gets expanded by [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).
- This algorithm is not good since you're calling `head` and `awk` 4 times, whereas you don't need a single external process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want it specifically looped as i will use the values further in the script for analysis. Thats the reason i want it looped.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt print out any values.

Comment: @Vignesh, of course it does! (will edit again the first edit so that you have the complete commands).

Answer (score 1):

You can print it using awk itself:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=2; i<=5; i++) print $i}' smaller.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that your assignment syntax is wrong. Change this:

```
set snp = head -n 1 smaller.txt | awk '{print $i}'
```

to this:

```
snp=$(head -n 1 smaller.txt | awk '{print $i}')
```

That is:

- Do not use `set`. `set` is for setting shell options, numbered parameters, and so on, not for assigning arbitrary variables.
- Remove the spaces around `=`.
- To run a command and capture its output as a string, use `$(...)` (or `` `...` ``, but `$(...)` is less error-prone).

That said, I agree with gniourf_gniourf's approach.

Comment: I tried corrections but i get this error for: Command not found.
do: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @Vignesh: Apparently you are not running your script in Bash?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative; not necessarily better or worse than any of the others:

```
for n in $(head smaller.txt)
do
  echo ${n}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

somthin like

```
  for x1 in $(head -n1 smaller.txt );do 
      echo $x1
  done
```